# Getting error Source parameter Null While Accessing Azure Community Gallery (preview) through PowerShell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to access Image in Community Gallery (Preview) currently Microsoft has published code/script in Azure CLI which is working

but for my project, I'm trying to access it through PowerShell but While running the script I got an error saying that the source parameter can not be null, it may be Powershell not able to get to ImageID
/CommunityGalleries/imtestgallery-71daa447-fde6-408b-a415-ce2a3126d8e9/Images/DLAPImage/Versions/latest

Also we tried by using
-SourceImageId $imageDefinition.Id.ToString()

-Set-AzVMSourceImage -Id $imageDefinition.Id |

&
-Image $imageDefinition `

```
enter code here 
#connect to Azure account

Connect-AzAccount

$resourceGroup = "RG-ptpl-APM2"
$location = "canadacentral"
$vmName = "VMlocgal"
$imageDefinition = "/CommunityGalleries/imtestgallery-71daa447-fde6-408b-a415-ce2a3126d8e9/Images/DLAPImage/Versions/latest
" ` 

$vm=New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize "standard_B2ms" `

$cred = Get-Credential `
   -Message "Enter a username and password for the virtual machine."

# Create a resource group
New-AzResourceGroup `
   -Name $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location

$subnetConfig = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
   -Name mySubnet `
   -AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24

$vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork `
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location `
   -Name MYvNET `
   -AddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/16 `
   -Subnet $subnetConfig

$pip = New-AzPublicIpAddress `
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location `
  -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)" `
  -AllocationMethod Static `
  -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4

$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
   -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  `
   -Protocol Tcp `
   -Direction Inbound `
   -Priority 1000 `
   -SourceAddressPrefix * `
   -SourcePortRange * `
   -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
   -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow
$nsg = New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup `
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location `
   -Name myNetworkSecurityGroup `
   -SecurityRules $nsgRuleRDP
$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface `
   -Name $vmName `
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location `
   -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id `
   -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id `
   -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id `


#create VM 
   New-AzVM `
    -Credential $cred `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
    -Location $location `
    -size "standard_B2ms" `
    -SubnetName "myImageSubnet" `
    -Image $imageDefinition `
    -SecurityGroupName "myImageNSG" ` -PublicIpAddressName "myImagePIP" `
    -Image $imageDefinition `

#SourceImageId $imageDefinition.Id.ToString() `


#Set-AzVMSourceImage -Id $imageDefinition.Id | # This is to use the gallery defined image from before

#Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $Interface.Id |
#Set-AzVMBootDiagnostic -disable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the az powershell support is out for community galleries yet. az cli is supported.

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).